# using regular expressions to exclude characters in a string search?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working with a Python 2.7.2 script to find lists of words inside of a text file that I'm using as a master word list.

I am calling the script in a terminal window, inputting any number of regular expressions, and then running the script.

So, if I pass in the two regular expressions "^.....$" and ".*z" it will print every five letter word that contains at least one "z".

What I am trying to do is add another regular expression to EXCLUDE a character from the strings. I would like to print out all words that have five letters, a "z", but -**not**- a "y".

Here is the code:

```
import re
import sys

def read_file_to_set(filename):
    words = None
    with open(filename) as f:
        words = [word.lower() for word in f.readlines()]
    return set(words)

def matches_all(word, regexes):
    for regex in regexes:
        if not regex.search(word):
            return False
    return True

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Needs a source dictionary and a series of regular expressions"
else:
    source = read_file_to_set(sys.argv[1])
    regexes = [re.compile(arg, re.IGNORECASE)
               for arg in sys.argv[2:]]
    for word in sorted(source):
        if matches_all(word.rstrip(), regexes):
            print word,
```

What modifiers can I put onto the regular expressions that I pass into the program to allow for me to exclude certain characters from the strings it prints?

If that isn't possible, what needs to be implemented in the code?

Answer (score 33):

Specifying a character that doesn't match is done with like this (this matches anything except a lower case letter):

```
[^a-z]
```

So to match a string that does not contain "y", the regex is: `^[^y]*$`

Character by character explanation:

`^` means "beginning" if it comes at the start of the regex.
Similarly, `$` means "end" if it comes at the end.
`[abAB]` matches any character within, or a range. For example, match any hex character (upper or lower case): `[a-fA-F0-9]`

`*` means *0 or more of the previous expression*.
As the first character inside `[]`, `^` has a different meaning: it means "not". So `[^a-fA-F0-9]` matches any non-hex character.

When you put a pattern between `^` and `$`, you force the regex to match the string exactly (nothing before or after the pattern). Combine all these facts:

`^[^y]*$` means *string that is exactly 0 or more characters that are not 'y'*. (To do something more interesting, you could check for non-numbers: `^[^0-9]$`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Would you mind explaining what each character in the "^[^y]*$" is doing? 

I am only beginning to work with computer programming / Python and I have seen each of those characters in the documentation for regexes but could not think to combine them like that for that result.

Comment: This is very helpful explanation thank you. Can you explain how to make it so that you can combine 2 regex 'NOT'/exclude statements? For example, what would it look like if you wanted to match some string that is not y AND it's also not q?

Comment: @EazyC If the exclusion is characters, it's just [^yq]*. If full strings, it's actually quite a bit harder. I don't know how offhand, but I think you can do it with negative lookaheads/lookbehinds. Regular expressions are about matching characters, but they aren't as powerful when it comes to *not* matching characters. Hence, some regex engines don't even support lookaheads/lookbehinds. (The difference is that they match isn't about the current character, but potential future/previous characters.) So to do a search for "not this and not that", you need negative lookahead/lookbehind.

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish this with `negative look arounds`. This isn't a task that Regexs are particularly fast at, but it does work. To match everything except a sub-string `foo`, you can use:

```
>>> my_regex = re.compile(r'^((?!foo).)*$', flags = re.I)
>>> print my_regex.match(u'IMatchJustFine')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1034ea738>
>>> print my_regex.match(u'IMatchFooFine')
None
```

As others have pointed out, if you're only matching a single character, then a simple not will suffice. Longer and more complex negative matches would need to use this approach.